# How to add buttons in ionic navbar based on a state

Tags: ionic-framework

I have two buttons in the nav-bar that i would like to be displayed on a certain state

**html**

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive ">
        <ion-nav-buttons>
            <a class="button" ng-click="usersignin()" ng-show="state=='app.login'">Signup</a>
            <a class="button" ng-click="userlogin()" ng- show="state=='login'">Login</a>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: why doesnt the code above work? If you have a $scope.state is should...

Comment: No am using the controller stateprovider state not the scope state

Comment: without seeing this code in context, we can only guess what you are trying to do... I suggest you edit the question and provide more information

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS provides `$on`, and `$broadcast` services for event-based communication between controllers.

Firstly create  two `$on` methods  for  catching  the event dispatched by $broadcast.

**controller**

```
$scope.logged = false;
$scope.$on('logged', function(value) {
    $scope.logged = true;
});
$scope.$on('loggedout', function(value) {
    $scope.logged = false;
});
```

Then `$broadcast` dispatches an event .

If the user logged ,

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('logged');
```

If the user logged out ,

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('loggedout');
```

**html**

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive ">
        <ion-nav-buttons>
            <a class="button" ng-click="usersignin()" ng-if="logged'">Signup</a>
            <a class="button" ng-click="userlogin()" ng-if="!logged">Login</a>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
</ion-view>
```

If you have any doubts.Please let me know.Thanks